# Firebase Orderby Query not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to used orderby score Json on w.

My Json

```
{  "score": {
"Abc": {
  "value": 5,
  "w": 60
},
"RRRR": {
  "value": 3,
  "w": 20
},
"Ral": {
  "value": 4,
  "w": 50
}  }}
```

My Android code is for fetching data of score.

```
  myRef.child("score").orderByChild("w").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            //  String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + dataSnapshot.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

Getting the o/p as  (wrong)

```
DataSnapshot { key = score, value = {Ral={w=50, value=4}, RRRR={w=20, value=3}, Abc={w=60, value=5}} }
```

I want to used order on w in on score and expect out

```
{  "score": {
"RRRR": {
  "value": 3,
  "w": 20
},
"Ral": {
  "value": 4,
  "w": 50
},
"Abc": {
  "value": 5,
  "w": 60
}  }}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong. There is no child "w" to your key "score". And point #2, sorting works on array, not on JSONObject items I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try iterating over results like following (assuming you have `Score` java object corresponding to score data)

```
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Score score = childSnapshot.getValue(Score.class);
}
```

Comment: myRef.child("score").orderByChild("w") is not working

Comment: @RahulGiradkar just to clarify....by "not working" you're saying that what you see when you log `dataSnapshot.toString()` isn't what you expect?  Have you tried the code I have above?